# Python Venv with Windows Linux Subsystem

Tags: windows-10, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just started using Ubuntu on Windows and was impressed with what it could interact with that was Windows things, files and some programs, etc. but I was wondering if anyone has tried or knew more about the possibility of setting up a virtual environment for python that could be used by both windows and the Linux subsystem. Ideally my thought process would be to have the venv that I could install packages to from either a windows pip command or a Linux pip command. Would this work?